# Ask for advice on the sdcard permissions management principle

Tags: android, permissions, android-sdcard

- Why are the permissions of all files **075** in android?
- How to implement this function?
- Or what is the principle of sdcard permission management?

Answer (score 0):

There is no permission management on the SD card/external storage. It uses the VFAT filesystem which does not support permissions. On newer phones, 'external' storage is actually internal and the SD card is emulated for backward compatibility. Any app can read files from external (shared) storage without special permissions, for writing you need to add the WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission to the manifest. BTW, the permission is `0775` with owner root and group `sdcard_rw`